# order y axis bar plot asc or desc

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This code gives the plot underneath. The plot is ordered alphabetical. How can I make the Y axis ordered desc or asc based on value of x axis (x axis are euro's in this case). Thanks!

'''

```
df.groupby(['Type']).sum()['Bedrag'].plot.barh(y='Type');
```

'''
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sort_values` function:

```py
df.groupby(['Type']).sum()['Bedrag'].sort_values().plot.barh(y='Type')
```

You can pass the `ascending` parameter to specify if you want to sort asc or desc:

```py
...sort_values(ascending=True)
...sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer so other people can see it's closed :)